# How to debug and fix incompatible AngularJS components?

Tags: angularjs, treeview, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using [angular.tree](http://github.com/dump247/angular.tree) and the Accordion in [UI Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/).  The tree properly receives events when placed outside of the accordion, but not when placed within it.

Demo here:  [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/XjR7SnLuEo7fPgRN2adN)

```
<p>Accordion:  Click "Tree in accordion" below to show tree</p>

<div ng-controller="TestController">
    <accordion close-others="true">
        <accordion-group heading="Tree in accordion">
          <ul ng-tree="model" multiple>
              <!-- PROBLEM:  doSelected() is not called -->
              <li select="doSelected()">{{item.name}}</li>
          </ul>
        </accordion-group>
        <accordion-group heading="Other">
          <h1>Other</h1>
        </accordion-group>
    </accordion>

<hr>

<p>Another tree</p>
          <ul ng-tree="model2" multiple>
              <!-- doSelected2() is correctly called, see alert output -->
              <li select="doSelected2()">{{item.name}}</li>
          </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: So what is your question? Be more specific.

Comment: How do I receive events from the tree in the accordion?  And how to go about debugging what the incompatibility is.  Because it seems this kind of thing is quite common when gluing AngularJS components together in a SPA.

Comment: How do I get doSelected() to be called from the tree in the accordion?  (Since doSelected2() is called correrctly for the tree outside of the accordion.)